# Pulling in external content from within CouchDB view

Tags: couchdb

Does CouchDB allow you to call an external web service from within the definition of your view? I basically want to resolve a woeid (where on earth id) using Yahoo's API's and update a view accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot. The reason is that view indexes need to be completely self-contained. Using any external source would require the view index to be recalculated upon **every** change of that external resource. (not even to mention that CouchDB has no way of knowing when an external change has occurred.)

For this same reason, you cannot use CommonJS modules in your map/reduce (view) functions, as the server would have no way of knowing what changes to any CommonJS modules (in any design document) would have any effect on a given view. The only solution would be to update the view **every** time a change is made to **any** design document, which nobody would ever want.

I would recommend you look into [GeoCouch](http://vmx.cx/cgi-bin/blog/index.cgi/geocouch-the-future-is-now:2010-05-03%3aen,CouchDB,Python,Erlang,geo) for utilizing positioning in your project.